# Can't get the footer on top of background image

Tags: css, z-index, footer

I just want the footer to appear on top of the background image. There is a background image which is the color and a logo of the company full screen except of the bottom 2 cm. There I want simple text with a link. Will do that myself, but cant get the text on top of the background color or background image. 
Here is the HTML:

```
<link href="voorblad.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.poptrox-1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static_init.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="bg1"></div>
     <img alt="full screen background image" src="gallery/voorblad.jpg" id="full-screen-background-image" /> 
  <div id="wrapper">
    </div>
    <footer>
    <p><h2>Framing your memories. Enter here. </h2></p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my css:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y:hidden;

}

#full-screen-background-image {
  z-index: 2;
  min-height: 90%;
  min-width: 1024px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  min-height: 400px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  color: #333;
}
#bg1 {
    min-width: 1255px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1090px;
    background: url(images/bg1.jpg) top center no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

#footer { 
    position:relative;
    bottom:0;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle pls? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few basic things:

1. What is the purpose of the empty bg1 and wrapper divs?
2. You have css for an element with ID 'footer', but there is no such element in your html.
3. Wrapping an h2 tag in a p tag is semantically incorrect.

A quick clean-up gives us something like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="full-screen-background-image"></div> 
    <div id="footer">
        <h2>Framing your memories. Enter here. </h2>
    </div>
</body>
```

Try adding a working jsfiddle so people can help you better. I can't access your local image, so I used a red background. See this fiddle for a basic idea of positioning one item on top of another: https://jsfiddle.net/cp35y75z/1/

If you use position: absolute instead of position: relative the element will not take up space in the DOM, meaning there will be no white space where the footer would have been originally.

Comment: I'm not to familiar with jsfiddle now, I will figure it out as soon as I possible. Here is a link to the page at this stage:

Comment: Alright, either remove the '#' before footer in your css, or add 'id="footer"' to your footer tag in your html, to make sure your styling is applied to the correct element.

In your css for the footer, change 'position: relative' to 'position: absolute'. That should be a good start.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was an excellent start. I can now see the footer (text). I will now style the text and create the link to enter.

Answer (score 0):

To style the footer make sure you take away the # unless you have an ID on the element. The proper css should look like this:

```
 footer { 
position:relative;
bottom:0;
z-index: 3;
}
```